# Multiple FabricTransportServiceRemotingListeners in a Single Service

Tags: microservices, azure-service-fabric

I'd like to be able to expose multiple FabricTransportServiceRemotingListeners from a single Stateless service inside my cluster. I've attempted to register the listeners as follows:

```
    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new ServiceInstanceListener(
                serviceContext =>
                    new FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener(serviceContext, new SqlCategoryCommandService(), new FabricTransportListenerSettings()
                    {
                        EndpointResourceName = "CategoryCommandEndpoint"
                    }), "SqlCategoryCommandService"),

            new ServiceInstanceListener(
                serviceContext =>
                    new FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener(serviceContext, new SqlCategoryQueryService(), new FabricTransportListenerSettings()
                    {
                        EndpointResourceName = "CategoryQueryEndpoint"
                    }), "SqlCategoryQueryService")
        };
    }
```

However when I make a proxy to the `ICategoryQueryService` which is implemented by the second listener this exception regarding an unimplemented Interface method is thrown leading me to believe that the first listener is incorrectly responding to all Proxy calls.

```
"Interface id '740213831' is not implemented by object 'TaxonomyService.SqlCategoryCommandService'"
```

I'm creating the Proxy using the following code:

```
var proxy = ServiceProxy.
     Create<ICategoryQueryService>(new Uri("fabric:/Taxonomy/TaxonomyService"));
```

Is the scenario I've described possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was answered correctly earlier by another user but it got deleted by a mod for whatever reason, so for posterity:

**Yes** this is possible. You just have to specify the listener name when you create the service proxy:

```
var proxy = ServiceProxy.Create<ICategoryQueryService>(new Uri("fabric:/Taxonomy/TaxonomyService"), listenerName: "SqlCategoryQueryService");
```

Comment: I've seen similar questions, and confusion with multiple listeners. Would it make more sense to make name required parameter and not optional?

Comment: I have multiple listeners - WcfCommunicationListener and the default for SF. I am trying to find the service by the default (not Wcf) but when I call a method it will return an error from Wcf as if I am trying to find the service by Wcf.

Comment: I am not able to make this multiple listeners work: yield return
                new ServiceReplicaListener(context => new FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener(context, this),
                    "ReadWriteCommunicationListener");yield return
                new ServiceReplicaListener(context => new FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener(context, this),
                    "ReadOnlyCommunicationListener");